# adding a products per page dropdown to woocommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to add a 'products per page' dropdown to my woocommerce storefront child theme without using a plugin. I'm adding the below code to my functions.php [source](http://pixelstores.com/products-per-page-dropdown-tutorial-for-woocommerce/)

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'ps_selectbox', 25 );
function ps_selectbox() {
    $per_page = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'perpage', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);     
    echo '<div class="woocommerce-perpage">';
    echo '<span>Per Page: </span>';
    echo '<select onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value">';   
    $orderby_options = array(
        '8' => '8',
        '16' => '16',
        '32' => '32',
        '64' => '64'
    );
foreach( $orderby_options as $value => $label ) {
    echo "<option ".selected( $per_page, $value )." value='?perpage=$value'>$label</option>";
}
echo '</select>';
echo '</div>';
}


add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'ps_pre_get_products_query' );
function ps_pre_get_products_query( $query ) {
    $per_page = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'perpage', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    if( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && is_post_type_archive( 'product' ) ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', $per_page );
    }
}
```

When I do this, the drop down box shows but any option I choose just takes me back to the front page of my theme.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: There is short code in woocommerce

Comment: do you have an example of how to add a dropdown using shortcode?

Answer (score 9):

> You can add the below codes into ***functions.php*** file. ***[Reference:](http://pixelstores.com/products-per-page-dropdown-tutorial-for-woocommerce/)***

The first step is to display a select box on the shop archive page. With some basic php we can echo a select box via the **woocommerce_before_shop_loop** hook.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'ps_selectbox', 25 );
function ps_selectbox() {
    $per_page = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'perpage', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);     
    echo '<div class="woocommerce-perpage">';
    echo '<span>Per Page: </span>';
    echo '<select onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value">';   
    $orderby_options = array(
        '8' => '8',
        '16' => '16',
        '32' => '32',
        '64' => '64'
    );
    foreach( $orderby_options as $value => $label ) {
        echo "<option ".selected( $per_page, $value )." value='?perpage=$value'>$label</option>";
    }
    echo '</select>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Some **inline jQuery has been added so everytime the select box is changed the “products per page” varibale is sent to the browser**.

**The filter_input() function gets the external variable** which in this case is **the number of products to show and sanitizes** it.

Now everything is in place we can **run the pre_get_posts hook with number of products per page via the “get” method**.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'ps_pre_get_products_query' );
function ps_pre_get_products_query( $query ) {
   $per_page = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'perpage', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
   if( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && is_post_type_archive( 'product' ) ){
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', $per_page );
    }
}
```

**This is the most simpliest of methods to add a “products per page” dropdown for your WooCommerce store**, alternativle you could go about using an ajax method.

Comment: Mark this one as a correct solution. Working like a charm.
For better knowledge, I have used the Astra theme, WP bakery builder along with for the filtration I have used WOOF plugin. But WOOF don't provide the Products per page feature. So, this hook works for me. Thanks Tanmay.

Comment: This is a nice method, but it creates a 404 error when you activate it on a paginated page that should not exist when the products per page changes. I have outlined the issue in a separate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73704776/how-do-you-remove-the-pagination-section-of-a-wordpress-url-whilst-also-adding-a, perhaps you might know a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following code taken from here-

http://designloud.com/how-to-add-products-per-page-dropdown-to-woocommerce/?showmodaldialog=1#comment-1554

```
// Lets create the function to house our form
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_catalog_ordering', 30 );

function woocommerce_catalog_page_ordering() {
?>
<?php echo '<span class="itemsorder">Items Per Page:' ?>
    <form action="" method="POST" name="results" class="woocommerce-ordering">
    <select name="woocommerce-sort-by-columns" id="woocommerce-sort-by-columns" class="sortby" onchange="this.form.submit()">
<?php

//Get products on page reload
if  (isset($_POST['woocommerce-sort-by-columns']) && (($_COOKIE['shop_pageResults'] <> $_POST['woocommerce-sort-by-columns']))) {
        $numberOfProductsPerPage = $_POST['woocommerce-sort-by-columns'];
          } else {
        $numberOfProductsPerPage = $_COOKIE['shop_pageResults'];
          }

//  This is where you can change the amounts per page that the user will use  feel free to change the numbers and text as you want, in my case we had 4 products per row so I chose to have multiples of four for the user to select.
            $shopCatalog_orderby = apply_filters('woocommerce_sortby_page', array(
            //Add as many of these as you like, -1 shows all products per page
              //  ''       => __('Results per page', 'woocommerce'),
                '20'        => __('20', 'woocommerce'),
                '-1'        => __('All', 'woocommerce'),
            ));

        foreach ( $shopCatalog_orderby as $sort_id => $sort_name )
            echo '<option value="' . $sort_id . '" ' . selected( $numberOfProductsPerPage, $sort_id, true ) . ' >' . $sort_name . '</option>';
?>
</select>
</form>

<?php echo ' </span>' ?>
<?php
}

// now we set our cookie if we need to
function dl_sort_by_page($count) {
  if (isset($_COOKIE['shop_pageResults'])) { // if normal page load with cookie
     $count = $_COOKIE['shop_pageResults'];
  }
  if (isset($_POST['woocommerce-sort-by-columns'])) { //if form submitted
    setcookie('shop_pageResults', $_POST['woocommerce-sort-by-columns'], time()+1209600, '/', 'www.your-domain-goes-here.com', false); //this will fail if any part of page has been output- hope this works!
    $count = $_POST['woocommerce-sort-by-columns'];
  }
  // else normal page load and no cookie
  return $count;
}

add_filter('loop_shop_per_page','dl_sort_by_page');
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_catalog_page_ordering', 20 );
```