# How do you remove the pagination section of a Wordpress URL whilst also adding a query to the end?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, drop-down-menu

I have assembled some custom code which I am using in my `functions.php` file on my Wordpress/Woocommerce site. The code was originally sourced from here: [adding a products per page dropdown to woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42744586/adding-a-products-per-page-dropdown-to-woocommerce).

**My code is designed to add a products per page (PPP) drop down box to any archive pages which contain more than one paginated pages worth of products.**

The issue I am facing can be highlighted using the following scenario:

- A theoretical archive page contains 100 products.
- The PPP function allows for '12', '24', '36' or 'all' products to show.
- The default is set to show '12' products per page.
- If you navigate to page 6 on this archive, everything works correctly (6 x 12 = 72 [which is less than 100]).
- If you now change the dropdown to '36', because page 6 (6 x 36 = 216 [which is more than 100]) doesn't exist due to a lack of products, a 404 error is presented instead.

The current code can be found here:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'UmbrellaTrading_products_per_page_archive_dropdown', 25 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'UmbrellaTrading_products_per_page_archive_dropdown', 25 );
function UmbrellaTrading_products_per_page_archive_dropdown() {
    
    $per_page = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'perpage', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        echo '<div class="utwc-perpage">';
        echo '<select onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value">';
    $orderby_options = array(
        '12' => '12',
        '24' => '24',
        '36' => '36',
        '-1' => 'All'
    );
    
    foreach( $orderby_options as $value => $label ) {
        echo "<option ".selected( $per_page, $value )." value='?perpage=$value'>$label</option>";
    }
        echo '</select>';
        echo '</div>';
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'UmbrellaTrading_products_per_page_archive_dropdown_pre_query' );
function UmbrellaTrading_products_per_page_archive_dropdown_pre_query( $query ) {
    
    $per_page = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'perpage', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    
    if( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && is_post_type_archive( 'product' ) || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', $per_page );
    }
}
```

The issue seems to be a result of the URL structure. It initially leaves the URL untouched:

> https://umbrellatrading.co.uk/shop

It also leaves the URL untouched when pagination is triggered:

> https://umbrellatrading.co.uk/shop/page/3

This is where the issue then arises; Because the URL currently adds the PPP code **after** the pagination, when a PPP URL is generated for a page that doesn't exist, there is nothing preventing this within the code, so a 404 occurs.

> https://umbrellatrading.co.uk/shop/page/3?perpage=24

In order for the code to work correctly and without error, I believe the correct URL behaviour should be set (as below) to always redirect to the first page of the referring URL's pagination results, i.e. If you're on page 3 of an archive results page and you trigger the PPP code by selecting from the dropdown on the front end, you should be redirected to page 1 of the same archive level, only with the amended PPP. The URL should therefore look like this.

> https://umbrellatrading.co.uk/shop?perpage=24

**My question: How can I remove the pagination section ('*/page/3*' in the example above) of the URL from within my code, but still add the PPP query to the end?**

*To assist; I can see the full URL is being picked up here in my code: `echo '<select onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value">';`, however I am unsure how to cut this into pieces and reconfigure it to show the correct URL structure.*

Comment: I believe you must get the current wp_query, get the total result count, the current page: and check if the "perpage" is possible or not.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Mtxz. You can see the correct solution to my issue below in the form of the accepted answer. Hopefully the code will help anyone else that requires a **'Products per Page'** dropdown on a WooCommerce site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `onchange` event on the `select` tag to not only add the `perpage` parameter but also remove the `/page/X` part in the URL:

```php
echo '<select onchange="if(this.value) window.location.href=window.location.pathname.replace(/\\/page\\/\\d+$/,\'\')+\'?\'+this.value">';
```

Here I used the `/\/page\/\d+$/` regexp to remove the pagination at the end of the current path (escaped when included in PHP string)

Comment: This answer is spot on. It solves exactly what my question asks and having spent the past hour testing it on my website, I can confirm it appears to be bug free - Thank you very much for your help!